# Randomly partition Mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

So i have a mongodb database and would like to partition it randomly.

By this i mean the database is of size $s$ and I would like to have it split so that I have $frac{s}{2}$ to train my classifier on and $frac{s}{2}$ to test it's accuracy on. ~~ Cross Fold validation. How can i do that? I was thinking assigning every entry an integer and then given a range from 0 to 1000 just choosing a random sampling. The problem is that I don't know when it updates and when it inserts. So I would only increment the value to insert if it was a new entry. So i'm thinking to use getLastError maybe to check that?

I feel like there's a better way to do this....

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: I have an idea but it is depending on your mongodb deployment (are there more than this collection) the collection and document size (1MB/Doc?) and performance specs (how many inserts and updates a sec?).

Comment: so what happens is i have some 20 or so files with 200k lines in them. I parse every file sequentially and use inserts / updates via an internal cache I have. I'm thinking I just keep looking at the collection.size and use it's size as an extra field?

Also I'm going to put in some 5 or 6 collections into this db.

Average is around 3000 updates (pure update) or 10k inserts (pure inserts) . so assume updates since i am updating old entries most of the time.

Comment: One Idea is using sharding and a random number, lets say 0-100 as shard key (or first part of a compound key) and then manually split your data using these shards. Afterwards train your data by querying shard1 directly (without using mongos). downside: queries trough mongos are always scatter gather because the data is sharded randomly.. reduce Chunk Size to one (1MB) before inserting your test Data. (Please dont do that in production systems for CMS'es etc.. )

Comment: one computer is running the db and the inserting into the db program

Comment: Is that a requirement? Could you run two VM's then?

Comment: @Marc uhm.. unlikely. they want everything on one vm.

Comment: and I guessing it is not for dev it is for prod usage? blazingly fast etc?

Comment: @Marc technically it's for dev, but it needs to be able to act like a prod.

Comment: ok, well spawning two mongod instances on one os is not a good idea. ..but back to your question. could zou post a sample schema?